# Number of items per category in sql table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

How do i find how many items there are per unique user in a data base

So say i have hats gloves and lots of other elements in my data base that users have added

how would i find how much each one had

e.g. hats- 35
t-shirts -50

but the problem is the categories would change so it would have to get all the categories then do an MySQL search on each of them... i have done lots of different MySQL tries and they have all failed here is one

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) FROM cards GROUP BY username";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$users = $row[0];
```

and i dont know where to go from here

Comment: Can you post more SQL-Information? How are you Tables structured, how can you select all tshirts or hats? or what is a card etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do

```
select `item`,count(*) as `total` from `test` 
group by `item`
```

check here

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19250/1

You can change the query to have your field names in the query

Comment: does total become a variable?

Comment: its not a variable its alias so you can get that inside the while loop as while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query) ) {
        echo "item : ".$row["item"]."  Count :: ".$row["total"] ;
    }

Comment: Thank you :D but in that bit you have to use $row[1] becuase its the second perameter and not used as MYSQLI_ASSOC

Comment: can u post the table and some values in sqlfiddle.com and what you want to get ?